# More than one "oneachfeature" leaflet

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

i'm trying to combine two features on one layer, but can't put them at work at same time. One is highlighting the are that cursor is hovering on and other is getting info out on the popup. I have used this guide fo highlighting: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html (adding interaction part, tried to just merge this to the working info popup layer). In addition at the moment it's highlighting on hover, but would be nice if it would highlight on click. 
Code:

```
    function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: 'blue',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'grey',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

    L.geoJson(piirid, {style: style});

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }

    var geojson;
    // ... our listeners
    geojson = L.geoJson(piirid);

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature3(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            //click: zoomToFeature
        });
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(piirid, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature3
    });

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties) {
            layer.bindPopup("<br><b><big><u>Aadresss: " + feature.properties.L_AADRESS + "</br></b></big></u><br> <b>Maakond:&nbsp;</b>" + feature.properties.MK_NIMI
            + " <br><br>", {"offset":  [200, -50]});
        }

}
```

Thanks, Kristjan

Comment: Why not just use css selector `:hover` instead of javascript?

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: instead of setting the style manualy in javascript when the mousover event occures, you could use the css `:hover` selector. Somehting like this:

`.layer:hover{color:grey; background-color:blue; ...}`

Comment: I actually got it working on click, wich I prefer more, but thank you anyway for your answer, still need to get the highlight and popup working together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two functions, they use the same parameters might as well be complected as one function.

```
 function style(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: 'blue',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'grey',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
    }

    L.geoJson(piirid, {style: style});

    function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;

        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 5,
            color: '#666',
            dashArray: '',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });

        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
            layer.bringToFront();
        }
    }

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
    }

    var geojson;
    // ... our listeners
    geojson = L.geoJson(piirid);

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature3(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            //click: zoomToFeature
        });
        if (feature.properties) {
            layer.bindPopup("<br><b><big><u>Aadresss: " + feature.properties.L_AADRESS + "</br></b></big></u><br> <b>Maakond:&nbsp;</b>" + feature.properties.MK_NIMI
            + " <br><br>", {"offset":  [200, -50]});
        }
    }

    geojson = L.geoJson(piirid, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature3
    });
```